# Change data on route-back with Vue-Router

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, nuxt.js

I'm trying to append a query string of the data object to the URL, after that fetch some data from the server based on the query.

Adding the query string & deleting the query string by changing the data works, the only thing I can't seem to figure out is how to change the data by going back a page with vue-router.

Maybe good to mention that changing back the data by

```js
beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
   this.query = to.query
   next()
}
```

is working but also triggers the watcher that sets the query string.

This is what I got so far, can someone point me in the right direction?

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="">String</label>
      <input
        type="text"
        class="form-control"
        v-model="query.string"
        placeholder="string"
      >
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <label class="form-check-label">
        <input
          class="form-check-input"
          type="checkbox"
          v-model="query.boolean"
        > Boolean
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      query: {
        string: this.$route.query.string || "",
        array: this.$route.query.array
          ? this.$route.query.array.split(",")
          : [],
        boolean: this.$route.query.boolean || false
      }
    };
  },
  watch: {
    query: {
      deep: true,
      handler(newFilters) {
        const q = this.toQuerystring({
          ...this.query
        });
        const path = `${this.$route.path}?${q}`;
        this.$router.push(path);
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toQuerystring(object, parentNode = null) {
      let query = Object.entries(object)
        .map(item => {
          let key = parentNode ? `${parentNode}[${item[0]}]` : item[0];
          let value = item[1];
          if (Array.isArray(value)) {
            if (value.length > 0) {
              value = value.map(encodeURIComponent);
              return key + "=" + value.join(",");
            } else {
              return "";
            }
          } else if (value instanceof Object) {
            return toQuerystring(value, key);
          } else if (item[1] !== null && item[1] !== "" && item[1] !== false) {
            return [
              Array.isArray(item[0]) ? `${key}` : key,
              encodeURIComponent(item[1])
            ].join("=");
          }
          return "";
        })
        .filter(empty => empty)
        .join("&");
      return "?" + query;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Not very clear but when I'm dealing with query strings I watch the query string like `watch: {
         '$route.query.string': function(s){/* exec your changes*/}
        }`

Comment: If I'll do ```watch: { '$route.query.string': function(s){this.query.string = s.query.string}```, then the watcher will run because this watches the whole query data object